# Why can only download the first episode video on bilibili with youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I can download the first episode of a series.

```
 yutube-dl  https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846?p=1
```

Now I want to download all episodes of the series.

```
for i in $(seq  1  55)
do
    yutube-dl  https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846?p=$i
done
```

All other episodes except the first can't be downloaded ,both of them contains same error info such as below:

```
[BiliBili] 90163846: Downloading webpage
[BiliBili] 90163846: Downloading video info page
[download] 【合集300集全】地道美音 美国中小学教学 自然科学 社会常识-90163846.flv has already been downloaded
```

Please have a try and check what happens,how to fix then?
@Christos Lytras,strange thing happen with your code:

```
for i in $(seq  1  55)
do
    youtube-dl https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846?p=$i -o "%(title)s-%(id)s-$i.%(ext)s"
done
```

It surely can download video on bilibili,but all of downloaded video have different name and same content,all the content are the same as the first episode,have a try and check ,you will find that fact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error occurs because `youtube-dl` ignores URI parameters after `?` for the filename, so the next file it tries to download has the same name with the previous one and it fails because a file already exists with that name. The solution is to use the `--output` template filesystem option to set a filename which it'll have an index in its name using the variable `i`.

> [**Filesystem Options**](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options)
>
> ```
> -o, --output TEMPLATE            Output filename template, see the "OUTPUT
>                                  TEMPLATE" for all the info
> ```
>
> [**OUTPUT TEMPLATE**](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template)
>
> The `-o` option allows users to indicate a
> template for the output file names.

> The basic usage is not to set any template arguments when downloading
> a single file, like in `youtube-dl -o funny_video.flv "https://some/video"`. However, it may contain special sequences that
> will be replaced when downloading each video. The special sequences
> may be formatted according to [python string formatting operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). For
> example, `%(NAME)s` or `%(NAME)05d`. To clarify, that is a percent symbol
> followed by a name in parentheses, followed by formatting operations.
> Allowed names along with sequence type are:
>
> `id` (string): Video identifier
> `title` (string): Video title
> `url` (string): Video URL
> `ext` (string): Video filename extension
> ...

For your case, to use the `i` in the output filename, you can use something like this:

```
for i in $(seq  1  55)
do
    youtube-dl https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846?p=$i -o "%(title)s-%(id)s-$i.%(ext)s"
done
```

which will use the `title` the `id` the `i` variable for indexing and the `ext` for the video extension.

You can check the [**Output Template**](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) variables for more options defining the filename.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, bilibili.com has some Javascript involved to setup the video player and fetch the video files. There is no way so you can extract the whole playlist using `youtube-dl`. I suggest you use [Lux](https://github.com/iawia002/lux) which [supports Bilibili playlists](https://github.com/iawia002/lux#download-playlist) out of the box. It has installers for all major operating systems and you can use it like this to download the whole playlist:

```
lux -p https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846
```

of if you want to download only until 55 video, you can use `-end 55` cli option like this:

```
lux -end 55 -p https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846
```

> You can use the `-start`, `-end` or `-items` option to specify the download
> range of the list:
>
> ```
> -start
>       Playlist video to start at (default 1)
> -end
>       Playlist video to end at
> -items
>       Playlist video items to download. Separated by commas like: 1,5,6,8-10
> ```
>
> For bilibili playlists only:
>
> ```
> -eto
>       File name of each bilibili episode doesn't include the playlist title
> ```

If you want to only get information of a playlist without downloading files, then use the `-i` command line option like this:

```
lux -i -p https://www.bilibili.com/video/av90163846
```

will output something like this:

```
 Site:      哔哩哔哩 bilibili.com
 Title:     【合集300集全】地道美音 美国中小学教学 自然科学 社会常识 P1 【001】Parts of Plants
 Type:      video
 Streams:   # All available quality
     [64]  -------------------
     Quality:         高清 720P
     Size:            308.24 MiB (323215935 Bytes)
     # download with: lux -f 64 ...

     [32]  -------------------
     Quality:         清晰 480P
     Size:            201.57 MiB (211361230 Bytes)
     # download with: lux -f 32 ...

     [16]  -------------------
     Quality:         流畅 360P
     Size:            124.75 MiB (130809508 Bytes)
     # download with: lux -f 16 ...


 Site:      哔哩哔哩 bilibili.com
 Title:     【合集300集全】地道美音 美国中小学教学 自然科学 社会常识 P2 【002】Life Cycle of a Plant
 Type:      video
 Streams:   # All available quality
     [64]  -------------------
     Quality:         高清 720P
     Size:            227.75 MiB (238809781 Bytes)
     # download with: lux -f 64 ...

     [32]  -------------------
     Quality:         清晰 480P
     Size:            148.96 MiB (156191413 Bytes)
     # download with: lux -f 32 ...

     [16]  -------------------
     Quality:         流畅 360P
     Size:            94.82 MiB (99425641 Bytes)
     # download with: lux  -f 16 ...
```

Comment: Strange thing :all of downloaded video have different name and same content with above code.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature yes you're right. As I see now, this happens because there is some Javascript code involved when the browser loads the page which of course `youtube-dl` can't handle because it just downloads the source code, it's not a headless browser. This cannot be done by `youtube-dl` alone. Would you like to have a solution involving more tools including `youtube-dl`?

Comment: Sure, i like so.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature there is [Annie](https://github.com/iawia002/annie), a better tool than `youtube-dl` which it can download full Bilibili playlists and it supports all major operating systems. Check my updated answer for more details.